# The p tag position for chat received message and sent messages

Tags: html, css

i have a small issue that i couldn't figure it out, i have a sent message in p tag and received message in a p tag too all in one div tag, when i send a message i need it to be after the received messages not in the middle or at first, knowing that those two messages i sent on the right are after receiving those two other messages on the left i have tried "position:relative" and too many other solution but i did not find the key to it yet can any body help ? im using html5,css and javascript.

Тhis is how my messages looks like:

[image: Messages page]

```
<div> 
<div id="chat" style=" background-image:url(images/logos/backg.jpg);height: 400px;overflow: auto;"> 
<br> 
<p style="float:left" id="msg"></p> <br> <p style="float:right; position: relative;" id="msge"></p> 
</div> 
<input id="msgg" type="text" style=" background-color: white;width:100%" > 
<input type="button" value="Send" id="send" class="login-button button button-small button-green button-fullscreen full-bottom" > 
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide some code, so we know what you've done so far

Comment: the first p tag is filled by server data and the second is the message i send so i guess the issue is in the second p tag

Comment: add this code in your question, its too difficult to read

Comment: add p{clear:both;} to your css

Comment: thankkk you  – Rares Hideg :D that solved the prolem how can i rate you or something im new here